# Select a file based on string

Tags: c#, file

I have the files as follows:

Test_221218_123.txt

Test_221218_456.txt

Test_221218_789.txt

Here '221218' is the date. I have done a test as follows:

```
var d = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\");
var files = d.GetFiles().Where(f => f.Name.Contains("221218"));
```

For testing i'm passing the date is static just for testing purposes but it will be a variable when put in production. The above is selecting all files for me. I need to select the latest file (in term's of date).

I tried as below

```
var files = d.GetFiles().Where(f => f.Name.Contains("221218"));
//OR
var files = d.GetFiles().Where(f => f.Name.Contains("221218")).Select(f => f.LastWriteTime);
```

The first one get's me a list of all the files with `221218`. The second one gives me the date. How do I select the latest file?

Comment: var file = d.GetFiles().Where(f => f.Name.Contains("221218")).OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime).FirstOrDefault()

Comment: `var files = d.GetFiles().Where(f => f.Name.Contains("221218")).OrderBy(o => o.LastWriteTime).LastOrDefault();`

Comment: Excellent, thanks;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FileInfo latestByWriteTime = new DirectoryInfo( @"C:\" )
    .GetFiles()
    .Where( f => f.Name.Contains( "221218", StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase ) )
    .OrderByDescending( f => f.LastWriteTime )
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I actually got this myself right after I posted the question. And I'm glad I did it something similar to you answer. except for the `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase`. Is this only for ignoring case

Answer (score 0):

You could use `OrderByDescending` on the `LastWriteTime` property and then select the first in the list.  This would work as follows:

```
var file = d.GetFiles().Where(f => f.Name.Contains("221218")).OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime).FirstOrDefault();
```

Alternatively, you could consider naming your files using the `DateTime.ToFileTime()` method and then you could just select the latest one with the largest timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Check This:

```
var d = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\");
var files = d.GetFiles()
   .Where(f => f.Name.Contains("221218"))
   .OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime)
   .FirstOrDefault();
```

And for Date

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyy")
```

final Query

```
var d = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\");
var files = d.GetFiles()
   .Where(f => f.Name.Contains(DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyy")))
   .OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime)
   .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I guess `LastWriteTime` suits better as the files can be overwritten so creationtime will stay same.